# Redirecting WIX URL to another URL

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, velo

I have been searching for quite some time, and have tried various methods found on SO to no avail.

I need to figure out a way, using HTACCESS, to redirect URLs from Wix like this http://www.example.com/#!optician-trade/c1eh to another URL I specify.

The #! in the URL is causing me some trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash part of a URL is of client-side meaning only, and is not even *send* to the server by common browsers … so you **can not** rewrite based on it server-side, because your server never gets to see it.

If you want to redirect based on the hash, you need to do it client-side via JS.

Comment: Ok, that I can do to actually redirect the users. What about Google, and SEO? How can I keep the page reputation and pass it to the new pages? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Research: hashbang, escaped fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to 2018 - now Wix has [clean URLs](https://www.wix.com/blog/2016/06/how-boost-your-seo-with-the-perfect-url/) without the hashtags.

And for redirecting between different URLs, you need to set 301 redirections as decribed [here](https://support.wix.com/en/article/setting-up-301-redirects-from-one-url-to-another).

Comment: unfortunately those directions don't allow redirecting /