# Redirecting a wix website to a new website

Tags: square, velo

I know this question has been asked several times but I cannot find a satisfactory answer. Here [Redirecting WIX URL to another URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087429/redirecting-wix-url-to-another-url) and here [Redirect a wix website to a new external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970168/redirect-a-wix-website-to-a-new-external-website)

We just purchased a store and are trying to migrate the website to a new website so it is easier for us to take online payments and have it synced with our inventory and everything on square. However, I cannot figure out how to do a 301 redirect from the home page to the new website.

Comment: You can add `<http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://example.com/">` using the SEO Advanced Settings. It's not SEO recommended though ([Section Meta Refresh](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection#:~:text=moved-,meta%20refresh,-Meta))

Comment: Why is it not recommended?

Comment: This did not work. I pasted that into the SEO advanced settings and it says "Structured data must be inside a script tag"